# sketch affine varieties in software SINGULAR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have to solve the problem 4 of the section 2 in the text "Ideal, varieties and algorithms" made by D. Cox, J. Little and D. O'Shea. The problem is that I must sketch some affine varieties in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ in the software SINGULAR. For example $V(x+2, y-1.5,z)$. I tried to solving the system $f_1=f_2=f_3=0$, and the result is the point $(-2,1.5,0)$. This point is the variety correspondent. I used this code:

> LIB "surf.lib";
>   ring R= 0, (x,y,z), dp;
>   ideal H=x+2;
>   ideal L= y-3/2;
>   ideal K = z;
>   ideal Q=intersect(H,L,K);
>   plot(Q);
>   Close window to exit from `singularsurf`.

This code sketch the three maps $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}$, but I need sketch only the point, e.g., the intersection of this maps. Can someone help me to solve this?.

Comment: `surf` can't plot the point alone. If it could it would be by calling `plot(Q)` on `ideal Q=H+L+K`, the intersection of the varieties, but that gives me `cannot plot 3 equations in 3 variables`. Intersecting the ideals gives you the union of the planes as you've seen.

Comment: Hi. thanks for you support, with the code that a send before I sketched the three varieties. The intersection of these varieties is just the result that I want.